# Que tipo de roupa é uma quinzena?

Tags: vocabulário

Encontrei o termo *quinzena* na primeira frase d'A Ilustre Casa de Ramires de Eça de Queiroz:

> Desde as quatro horas da tarde, no calor e silêncio do domingo de
> Junho, o Fidalgo da Torre, em chinelos, com uma quinzena de linho
> envergada sobre a camisa de chita cor de rosa, trabalhava.

Os dicionários dizem que *quinzena* é uma espécie de jaquetão. Alguém teria uma descrição melhor que essa? Talvez uma foto.

Comment: Escreve Eça: "... trazia uma quinzena solta ..." referindo-se a Fradique Mendes, na Correspondência.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

O Houaiss descreve "quinzena" como um

> casaco masculino largo, curto, sem cintura marcada

Outra [fonte](https://folclore.pt/trajes-homem-mulher/) define "quinzena" como sinônimo de "jaqueta", que [é](https://dicionario.priberam.org/jaqueta) um

> Casaco curto, sem abas, que não ultrapassa a cintura

Então temos duas fontes descrevendo a roupa como um **casaco largo e curto**. Também talvez seja simples, já que lhe faltam abas e cintura, mas não estou certo, dado que o personagem é um fidalgo.

Mas uma [outra descrição](http://metalibri.wikidot.com/p:queiroza-casaramires-001) é

> jaquetão leve

e "jaquetão" [seria](https://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa/jaquet%C3%A3o) uma

> jaqueta larga, em geral feita de tecido grosso, que chega até abaixo da cintura

ou seja, **longa**. E uma ilustração (veja abaixo) aparentemente [presente](http://metalibri.wikidot.com/p:queiroza-casaramires-001) na edição de 1900 (também [aqui](https://projectoadamastor.org/a-ilustre-casa-de-ramires-eca-de-queiros/)) não oferece muitos detalhes, mas também parece retratar um casaco longo. Então não tenho muita certeza de que a aparência desse casaco é bem definida, embora ele provavelmente seja largo.

[image: ilustração do livro sobre a cena da pergunta]

Comment: Muito boa resposta!  Achei curioso notar que a primeira e a segunda definições são contraditórias. A primeira diz "sem cintura marcada", por isso passa na cintura mas sem alteração, sem moldar ao corpo. A segunda diz que não ultrapassa a cintura.

Comment: @ANeves Não diria que cheguem a ser contraditórias, casacos masculinos curtos ao ponto de não chegarem a ultrapassar a cintura são pouco comuns, então provavelmente é possível chamar de curto um que passe, mas não muito, da cintura.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta. Não é uma peça de roupa tão específica como pensei, mas, talvez, um termo genérico para casacos, jaquetas.

Comment: @Sidney É a impressão que tenho. Na verdade, creio que a maioria dos itens de vestuário têm definições relativamente vagas.